# Finding most common adjective in text (part of speech tagging)

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk

I have a dataset where i'm trying to find the most common adjective/verb/noun, I already used NLTK to tag the word, so now my dataframe is looking like this:

| Index | POS |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [('the', 'DT'),('quality', 'NN'),('of', 'IN'),('food', 'NN'),('was', 'VBD'),('poor', 'JJ')] |
| 1 | [('good', 'JJ'), ('food', 'NN'), ('for', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('price', 'NN')] |

Now how do i find what word is most commonly used as adjective for example

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line will find the most common adjective (`JJ`) per row:

```
df['adj'] = df['POS'].explode().loc[lambda x: x.str[1] == 'JJ'].str[0].groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                                                        POS   adj
0  [(the, DT), (quality, NN), (of, IN), (food, NN), (was, VBD), (poor, JJ)]  poor
1               [(good, JJ), (food, NN), (for, IN), (the, DT), (price, NN)]  good
```

This line will the most the common adjective in the whole dataframe:

```
most_common = df['POS'].explode().loc[lambda x: x.str[1] == 'JJ'].str[0].mode()[0]
```

Output:

```
>>> most_common
'good'
```

(Note that for your example data, there's an equal number of most-common values (i.e., 1) so this code will pick the first if that's the case.)